# numpy: how to assign an 1d array through filtering a 2d array?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a the following code:

```
import numpy as np

labels = np.array(["A", "B", "C"])

matrix = np.array([[True, False, False], [False, True, True], [False, False, True]])
```

How can I get a 2d array with labels wherever it is "True" in the matrix? Possibly with numpy operations only? So the desired output is:

```
[["A"], ["B", "C"], ["C"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```py
[labels[m].tolist() for m in matrix]
```

and I'm guessing by 2D array you mean:

```py
np.array([labels[m].tolist() for m in matrix])
```